# Is there a notion of tunnel number for 2-knots?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, 2-knots

Given an embedded circle $K$ in $S^3$, the tunnel number of $K$ is the minimum number of embedded arcs one needs to add to $K$ so that the complement of $K$ and the arcs is a handlebody.

For an embedded sphere in $S^4$, is there an analogous definition? Has work been done about it?